# Does IdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveEnvelope get the entire message body?

Tags: delphi, indy

Does IdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveEnvelope method retrieve the entire message body or only the headers?

Comment: Have you checked [`the documentation`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdIMAP4_UIDRetrieveEnvelope@String@TIdMessage.html) ?

Comment: Yes, but its not clear. Not sure what 'envelope' means.

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: You should have a look at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501 to get the idea and namings behind the IdIMAP4 component. And it is the same as in real world ;o)

Comment: So does it get the message body? ..because an envelope does contain a letter..

Comment: No, it does not get the message body. You have to retrieve that separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that refers to envelopes only operates on headers, not on bodies.  Thus, `(UID)RetreiveEnvelope()` only retrieves headers, and even then only specific headers as defined by the IMAP standard:

```
Date
Subject
From
Sender
Reply-to
To
Cc
Bcc
In-reply-to
Message-id
```

To retrieve the actual body content, you need to use `(UID)RetrieveStructure()` to discover a message's MIME structure, then use `(UID)RetrievePart...()` or `(UID)RetrieveText...()` to retrieve the content of individual body parts as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebau: Thank you for the answer which is informative, and for the extra information about how to get the message. It saved me from posting another question about exactly that.